# formula crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

hola gente estoy teniendo problemas con esta formula:

```
stringvar alturaCalle;
stringvar depto;
if isNull({sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.numCalle})
then alturaCalle=" "
else
alturaCalle={sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.numCalle};
```

no se por qué alturacalle me devuelve "falso" cuando lo quiero mostrar en el reporte.. soy nuevo usando crystal report y no se bien como funciona la sintaxis acá

> La idea es que una vez evaluados los campos armar la cadena final para mostrar en el reporte, de la forma:

```
{sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.nombreProvincia}
+ ","  + {sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.nombreCiudad}
+ "," + {sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.nombreCalle}
+ " " + alturaCalle +" "+ depto;
```

no se por qué alturacalle me devuelve "falso" cuando lo quiero mostrar en el reporte.. soy nuevo usando crystal report y no se bien como funciona la sintaxis acá

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas definiendo una formula en un reporte de crystal

[If Expressions (Crystal Syntax)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b5cc3e6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)

no deberias asignar una variable sino retornar el valor que asignar al campo para poder visualizarlo

Solo veo que defines `stringvar`, pero deberias indicar el `scope` como ser usando `Local`

[Variable Declarations (Crystal Syntax)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b738206e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)

la asignacion se realiza con `:=`

Algo como ser

```
Local StringVar alturaCalle := "";
If Not(IsNull({sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.numCalle})) Then
  alturaCalle := {sp_reportePedidoCliente;1.numCalle};
```

Validas si es null usando

[Null Fields and Null Values (Crystal Syntax)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b6099e6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)